# How to make the this in the static function of the ES6 class point to the function itself

Tags: javascript, static, es6-class, this-pointer

I want get the static function name in ES6 class, and I did not get the correct result when I did this.

```
class Point {
  static findPoint() {
    console.log(this.name) // <- I want to print "findPoint" but get "Point"
  }
}
Point.findPoint()
```

What can I do to get the name of the static method?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: My business logic has many similar methods and they can throw errors. I want to return the name of the function that throws the error back to the client. I wrap this as a generic return method, but I don't know which method will throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create an `Error` and examine its stack - the top item in the stack will be the name of the current function:

```js
class Point {
  static findPoint() {
    const e = new Error();
    const name = e.stack.match(/Function\.(\S+)/)[1];
    console.log(name);
  }
}
Point.findPoint();
```

While `error.stack` is *technically* non-standard, it's [compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack#Browser_compatibility) with every major browser, including IE.

Answer (score 0):

`this.name` refers class name. Use `this.findPoint.name` to get static function name. Syntax must be `object.someMethod.name`. You have to say which method name you want. Hope this will help you.

```
class Point {
  static findPoint() {
    console.log(this.findPoint.name)
  }
}
Point.findPoint()
```